# Select row numbers of a data frame conditioning on another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that I want to find the row numbers where these rows are in common with another data frame.

To make the question clear, say I have data frame A and data frame B:

```
dfA <- data.frame(NAME = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 3),
                  TRIAL = rep(1:3, 2),
                  DATA = runif(6))
dfB <- data.frame(NAME = c("a", "b"), 
                  TRIAL = c(2, 3))
dfA
#   NAME TRIAL       DATA
# 1    a     1 0.62948592
# 2    a     2 0.88041819
# 3    a     3 0.02479411
# 4    b     1 0.48031827
# 5    b     2 0.86591315
# 6    b     3 0.93448264
dfB
#   NAME TRIAL
# 1    a     2
# 2    b     3
```

I want to get dfA's row number where dfA and dfB have the same NAME and TRIAL, in this case, row numbers are 2 and 6.

I tried the following code, gives me row 2, 3, 5, 6. It separately matches NAME and TRIAL, doesn't work.

```
which(dfA$NAME %in% dfB$NAME & dfA$TRIAL %in% dfB$TRIAL)
# 2 3 5 6
```

Then I tried to create a dummy column and match this col. Works, but the code would be verbose if dfB has many columns...

```
dfA$dummy <- paste0(dfA$NAME, dfA$TRIAL)
dfB$dummy <- paste0(dfB$NAME, dfB$TRIAL)
which(dfA$dummy %in% dfB$dummy)
# 2 6
```

I'm wondering if there are better ways to solve the problem, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
merge(transform(dfA, row.num = 1:nrow(dfA)), dfB)$row.num
# [1] 2 6
```

And if the whole goal of finding the indices is so that you can subset `dfA`, then you can just do `merge(dfA, dfB)`.

Answer (score 0):

Or use duplicated:

```
apply(dfB, 1, function(x)
  which(duplicated(rbind(x, dfA[1:2])))-1)
# [1] 2 6
```

Comment: but I like the merge way @flodel proposed MUCH better!

Comment: thanks for your input, clever use of duplicated, have to admit that I spend some time to understand :)